# What's "preauthorization" in a Cocoa app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, authorization

What's "preauthorization" in a Cocoa app? And why it always succeeds even when using a random auth right name? That is, why the following code never throws an error?

```
let rightName = ("some-random-string" as NSString).UTF8String
let flags = [.PreAuthorize, .ExtendRights, .InteractionAllowed]
SFAuthorization().obtainWithRight(rightName, flags: flags)
```

Comment: The code in the question was adapted from [Apple's example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002589-SW7).